# How can I use the same code for a password entry for different users in Java?

Tags: java, authentication, user-input

(Note: I am new to Java & Programming, and using Netbeans)

My task is to create code which will first ask for a username, and will then ask for a password. My solution to this was to have a separate block of code for each user's password input. However, this is very lengthy. The code I am using for password input is here:

```
List<String> passwords = new ArrayList<>();   //array which is populated by user input
    Scanner passwordinput = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.print("Create password? (y/n)");        //create password request
        if (passwordinput.next().startsWith("y")) {
            System.out.print("Create password (no spaces): ");
            passwords.add(passwordinput.next());
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);

    System.out.print("Enter password: ");                    //enter password request
    String enterpass;
    enterpass = passwordinput.next();

    if (passwords.contains(enterpass)) {
        System.out.println("wohoo you're in");
    } else {
        System.out.println("bad luck brudda");
    }
```

In summary, I am asking if the user wants to create a password, then they enter it (which is put into a string). Then, they are requested to enter that password in order to continue.

Is there any way I can use this same block of code for each user, but not have to duplicate it every time?

Any other improvements are welcome.

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary`. The key is the username, the value is the password. When a user attempts to log in, just look up their entry in the dictionary.

Comment: You want to wrap your password-creation code into a method, and make your password ArrayList a global variable that can be referenced by both your main execution method and the password-creation method.

Comment: And a dictionary does seem like a better solution than an ArrayList as it allows username/password combos.

Comment: @kgh in Java, you use a `Map` rather than a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Maps. In a HashMap you map a value to a fix key. So every username(key) could only exist one time but the password (value) could always be the same.
You would need a HashMap. This HashMap has a String as Key and a String as value. The key is your username and the Password is your value. So you do this like that:

```
HashMap<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
String username1 = "FIRST_USERNAME";
String password1 = "FIRST_PASSWORD";
String username2 = "SECOND_USERNAME";
String password2 = "SECOND_PASSWORD";
logins.put(username2, password2);
logins.put(username1, password1); // adds the username and the password to your "loginlist"
String inputUser = scanner.nextLine();    
String inputPassword = scanner.nextLine();
if(inputPassword.equals(logins.get(inputUser)){
 // Password and user correct
}
```

EDIT:
Here an example how to do it with methods. Maybe you understand better then. Hope you know something about exceptions. if not you should learn about them because they are essential for java

```
public class LoginManager {

private Map<String, String> logins;

public LoginManager() {
    this.logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public void logIn(final String pUserName, final String pPassword) {
    if (pPassword == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No password given");
    }
    if (!pPassword.equals(this.logins.get(pUserName))) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Wrong username or password");
    }
}

public void registerUser(final String pUserName, final String pPassword) {
    if (pUserName != null && pPassword != null) {
        if (!pUserName.isEmpty() && !pPassword.isEmpty()) {
            if (!this.logins.containsKey(pUserName)) {
                this.logins.put(pUserName, pPassword);
                return;
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Username already in use");
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Username or password not given");
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String choice1 = "1";
    final String choice2 = "2";
    LoginManager manager = new LoginManager();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean loginTried = false;
    while (!loginTried) {
        System.out.print("Register new user(1) or login (2): ");
        switch (input.nextLine()) {
            case choice1:
                System.out.print("New username: ");
                String userName = input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Password: ");
                String password = input.nextLine();
                try {
                    manager.registerUser(userName, password);
                    System.out.println("User registered");
                }
                catch (Exception error) {
                    System.out.println(error.getMessage());
                }
                break;
            case choice2:
                loginTried = true;
                System.out.print("Username: ");
                String loginName = input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Password: ");
                String loginPassword = input.nextLine();
                try {
                    manager.logIn(loginName, loginPassword);
                    System.out.println("Login was successfully");
                }
                catch (Exception error) {
                    System.out.println("Login failed: " + error.getMessage());
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid choice. Choose 1 or 2");
                break;
        }
    }
    input.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, however I still don't understand how I can add to the map? I am looking for code that takes the variables (or direct user input) and puts them as new entries into the map, which can then be compared too when putting in the user info.

Comment: username1/2 and password1/2 are added to the loginmap by the method logins.put(...). the put method of a map is like the add method of a list. it maps a value to the given key. every key can only exist 1 time. so if you use usernames as keys, they cant exist twice. but the password which is maped to the username, can be every time the same as the other passwords. the value can exist as often as you want it to in the map, just the key can only be added once. so use logins.put(username, password) to add something to the map. if you call logins.get(username) it returns the password of the user

Comment: This answers one of my other questions, how to use a block of code as a method- learn something new every day. Thank you for this code by the way, I am studying it and so far I am impressed with the complexity of it, but am happy that I am slowly understanding it. Thanks for the input!    The only other question I have is what is the point in using this. ?

Comment: this is a keyword. image you have two variables. one private int value and a parameter in a method. public int doSomething(int value); if you want to aces now the variable "value" in the method doSomething there are two variables caled value. the parameter and the private one. if you use this.value you are caling the private variable. if you call value without this you are caling the parameter :) this is a pointer to the object you are working on